# What does an unaugmented sigma field mean?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

What does an unaugmented sigma field mean in [Wikipedia's Girsanov's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girsanov_theorem)?

> Then for each $t$ the measure $Q$ restricted to **the unaugmented
>   sigma fields** $\mathcal{F}^W_t$ is equivalent to $P$ restricted to
>   $\mathcal{F}^W_t$.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely this means you are not completing the $\sigma$--fields by tossing in the subset of sets of probability zero.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reference saying so?